# Javascript scroll event adding class

Tags: javascript, scroll, hyperlink, position, viewport

Hello guys i have a problem with scroll event:

I want to add a class to some link when the section is in the viewport ( is visible ), but the problem is if my scroll position is between the `selected range`( in `if statement` ) everything is ok the `class` is added to the `link`. But if i continuously scroll to the next section the class is infinite added. How can i only add it once the `if statement` is true (scroll position is between the `selected range`) ?

```
// Element position
  const attractionSectionPos = Math.floor(ui.attractions_section.getBoundingClientRect().top);

// For intro section
  if(attractionSectionPos <= 250 && attractionSectionPos >= -450) {

    // Remove the active link if we have more than one
    document.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active'));
                
    // Add the class when section is in viewport
    document.querySelector('[data-link="attractions"]').classList.add('active');

    // Prevent default so we only add the class once
    e.preventDefault();

  // Remove the class if section is not in viewport
  } else { document.querySelector('[data-link="attractions"]').classList.remove('active') }
```

If i add `e.preventDefault()` it gives me a bunch of errors.

E.g: `Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`

[This is how my console looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5VAP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in the `if statement` the following:

`!document.querySelector('[data-link="attractions"]').classList.contains('active')`

Now everything works smoothly and adds the `class` only once when the `section` is in the `viewport`